# Dynamic SQL query to loop through records and find correct category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a 2 step process to determine material types for different components.

**Step 1**: this includes results from a different query containing RecordID and Component Name :

Sample records :

| RecordID | Component | Material |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BR39590 | 00000000000000564792 | 000000000002073757 |
| BR39590 | 00000000000000567649 | 000000000002073757 |
| BR39591 | 00000000000000567650 | 000000000002073758 |

Above RecordId's will contain several component numbers and corresponding Materials

2. Loop through the Material derived from above query result and join to a different table called 'Material' to determine Material type, if Material type belongs to 'A' or 'B' the process should exit out and insert the records into a new table. If Material type does not belong to 'A' or B then Query should go back to step 1 and fetch the next component to look for 'A' or 'B' or blank resultset.

| Material | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 000000000002073757 | A |
| 000000000002073758 | B |

Above 2 steps are repeated for all RecordID's

Final Result:

| RecordId | Material | Component | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BR39590 | 000000000002073757 | 00000000000000564792 | A |
| BR39590 | 000000000002073757 | 00000000000000567649 | A |
| BR39591 | 000000000002073758 | 00000000000000567650 | B |

Comment: What have you tried? You can loop through records, but it is not recommend and will not scale well. Just join your two tables and then there is not need to "loop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand what you mean, With dynamic SQL or coding in SQL environment, your wishes can be met, but there is a much, much easier way.

*with a `left join` you can find the end result.*

```
 select 
       c.RecordID,
       c.Material,
       c.Component,
       m.Category
 from components c left join material m on c.Material = m.Material
```